# How are the locations of the Olympics determined?

Tags: olympics, venues

In 2014, the Winter Olympics will be held in Sochi, Russia.  In 2016, the Summer Olympics will be held in Rio de Janiero, Brazil.

There are candidate cities that submit bids to host the Olympics. In some cases, competition venues are spread apart from one another. For example, the [2010 Winter Olympics in Vancouver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venues_of_the_2010_Winter_Olympics).

What is the procedure a city must take to be eligible to bid to to become a host for the Olympics? In addition, What competitive venues did Sochi, Rio, and Vancouver put in place to legitimately propose a bid to host a summer/winter Olympics?

Comment: For the edit claiming the details are a "red herring," please refer here: https://sports.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hosting the Olympic Games is respect each city is dreaming about and any city in the world can apply to host the Olympics.

There are two stages to the selection process:

**First stage** - Apply for hosting
Cities who apply prepare reports detailing their plans and capabilities to host the Olympic Games. The first stage is the application, where the cities respond to a detailed questionnaire about the master plan to host the Games, including: vision and legacy, the games concept and sports events, the Olympic Village, the center of international communications, experience in sports, environment and meterology, hospitality, transportation, healthcare, security and safety, telecommunications, energy, legal aspects, public and government support, and financing and marketing.

**Second Stage** -
After careful examination of the reports, the International Olympic Committee (IOC) publishes which cities have demonstrated the ability to host the games. These cities are the second stage where they meet another series of more in-depth questions. A Special Evaluation Committee of the IOC examines the proposals and visits the candidate cities. Finally a vote is held which determines the host city of the Olympic Games.

While last year London hosted the Games for the third time (more than any other city in the world), and Rio de Janeiro will host the games in 2016, the race to host the games in 2020 has not yet reached the finish line.

The IOC officially announced the three cities which have applied to host the Games in 2020 out of the cities which presented their candidacy:

- Istanbul, Turkey
- Tokyo, Japan
- Baku, Azerbaijan
- Doha, Qatar
- Madrid, Spain

First, the IOC accepted the proposals of Istanbul, Tokyo and Madrid. Later, Tokyo was announced as the host city of the 2020 Olympic Games.

Sources [1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Summer_Olympics) [2](http://www.olympic.org/host-city-election) [3](https://www.olympic.org/2020-host-city-election)